# Running stage when build triggers from feature branches on azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We need to run stage when build comes from feature branches, we create feature branches as below
feat/123
feat/abc...etc
so stage needs to be executed when build comes from any of feature branches like feat/*.

tried with setting up conditions as below but did not get succeeded.

```
jobs:
- job: DockerBuildtask
condition: and(succeeded(), or(eq(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop'), eq(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release'), eq(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/feat.*'), eq(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/bugfix.*')))

jobs:
- job: DockerBuildtask
condition: and(succeeded(), or(eq(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop'), eq(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release'), eq(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/feat/*.'), eq(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/bugfix/*.')))

jobs:
- job: DockerBuildtask
condition: and(succeeded(), or(eq(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop'), eq(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release'), eq(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/feat*.'), eq(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/bugfix*.')))
```

but could not succeded..  am i missing anything here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `eq(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/feat.')` and in your case it should be rather `contains(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/feat')`. I assumed that you have [CI triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers) set correctly.